# CSRF token is missing - React Frontend form with Flask backend

Tags: reactjs, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask backend with postresql hosted on Render, and I'm developing a separate React frontend locally. I'm encountering issues related to CSRF tokens when making POST requests relating to creating a new user. Creating a user on the Render page works fine, but not when I'm in my react, nor with Insomnia API Platform.

How can I securely access and include the CSRF token in requests from the React app when the two are on different domains? I'd like general guidance if I'm missing something here.

I did clone/download my Flask backend project in order to add error messages to the registration page. I already had `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`, but I changed it to `{{ form.csrf_token }}`, yet nothing improved. I have CORS enabled on the app. I was using flaskwtf, wtfforms, etc.

I've tried looking around but I've been having a lot of brain fog. Thank you and I appreciate any answers. Here's some snippets of code:

flask routes page snippet:

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = UserRegistrationForm()
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                first_name = form.first_name.data
                last_name = form.last_name.data
                username = form.username.data
                email = form.email.data
                password = form.password.data

                logger.debug(f"Form Data submitted: first_name={first_name}, last_name={last_name}, username={username}, email={email}, password={password}")

                user = User(email=email, username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=password, image_file='defaultuser.png')

                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                
                flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
            else:
                for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                    for error in errors:
                        logger.error(f'Error in field "{field}": {error}')
                flash(f'There was an error: {error}', 'danger')
                jsonify({'status': 'error', 'errors': error})
    except:
        logger.exception(f'An exception occurred: {str(Exception)}')
        raise Exception('Invalid Form Data: Please Check your Form')
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

I did try both but it didn't seem to matter:

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

```
<form method="POST"> 
{{ form.hidden_tag() }} 
<div class="form-group"> 
<-- the rest of the form -->
```

and here's some of the React code so far:

```
import { u_server_calls } from "../auth/server";

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await u_server_calls.post('register', data);
      console.log("User created", data);
      alert("User created!\n" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      setError('An error occurred while submitting the form');
      console.log("error creating user form", error);
    }
  };
 return (
// rest of my form
```

calling the server:

```
import axios from "axios";
const BASE_URL = "my_url_is_here"

export const u_server_calls = {

    getUsers: async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/users`);
            console.log(response.data.results[0])
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`failed to get user. error: ${error}`)
        }
    },
    post: async (url: string, data: any) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/${url}`, {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN,
                }
            }, data)
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    },
// rest of code (PUT and DELETE)
```

Oh, and while I was initially trying out my react code, after 'submitting' the form and making a POST request, the console would say 200 OK. But checking the logs in Render, i'd see the CSRF error, and my postgresql browser would have no new data.